# Missing languages in Language Support in 14.10

Tags: language-support, 14.10

I just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 14.10. And I wanna change the language to Faroese, which has been in all previous versions of Ubuntu in the Language Support, even though it's only 1% translated in launchpad.

[image]

If this is a bug or something, could someone help me to report it? I don't have much experience making bug reports.

Comment: I heard the other day that they have stopped shipping languages with less than 5% translated. I'm not quite sure what that means, but possibly it is the explanation.

Comment: I checked again today, and Faroese was in the list now :) Don't know why or anything, but it works great :D

Comment: Not for me. And no [language packs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-pack-fo) seem to have been released for 14.10. Are you really talking about 14.10 and the "Installed Languages" list which you showed us in the question?

Comment: I don't remember if I changed something in "Software & Updates". But maybe it has something to do with this: http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202014-11-26%2022:50:48.png ? I got no idea why or how it got in "Installed Languages"